# SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected EOF in opencart issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, opencart, opencart2.x

I am getting the following error when trying to access home page of opencart 2.1.0.1:

SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected EOF
OK

Its working fine in my local server. can't  work out how to identify what's causing the error though.I searched on Google, but no solution to solved my problem.Any ideas???

Comment: Check what is inside JSON. Maybe it's error with json headers? Show us more information instead of only error description

Comment: Need to see the code. EOF stands for "End of File". It happens often if you don't open/close tags properly. Check the respective .tpl file first. It could be something as silly as missing a bracket somewhere.